# find upcoming birthdays from database

Tags: mysql

I need to find upcoming birthday from database table name `users` and column name `u_bday` where `u_bday` is in varchar format.
i tried this but not work for me help.

```
$sql=" SELECT `f_name`,`u_bday` FROM  `users` 
       WHERE  DATE_ADD(`u_bday`, INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(`u_bday`)+  
              IF(DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) > DAYOFYEAR(u_bday),1,0) YEAR)  
       BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)";
```

what should i do???

Comment: _"what should i do???"_ - a little thing called _research_ ... http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+upcoming+birthday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this function to convert your varcher column to date format

```
str_to_date(  fieldname, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [date_diff](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function and query could be somthing like below

```
SELECT `f_name`,`u_bday` FROM  `users` 
WHERE  DATE_DIFF(`u_bday`, now()) > 1 
ORDER BY u_bday asc;
```